# Elastic Beanstalk access to local disk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When trying to open a file using Node.js on an EC2 instance I receive the error:

`{
  "errno": -13,
  "code": "EACCES",
  "syscall": "open",
  "path": "/tmp/uploads/50a4386c-5cdf-44ec-acb9-5d064b4be96a.jpeg"
}`

According the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_eacces_permission_denied) EACCES occurs when 'an attempt was made to access a file in a way forbidden by its file access permissions'. This suggests the user under which Node.js applications are run doesn't have access to `/tmp`. I've also tried writing to `/var/app/current` which is where Elastic Beanstalk deploys the source of the Node.js application. Neither location is writable.

How can I write to the local disk of an Amazon Linux EC2 instance deployed by Elastic Beanstalk?

Relevant instance information:

`EBS-optimized: False
Root device type: ebs
Root device: /dev/sda1
Block devices: /dev/sda1`

Policies applied:

`AmazonEC2FullAccess
AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess`

`/tmp` properties:

`drwxrwxrwt 20 root root  4096 Dec 30 03:50 tmp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the `uploads` directory inside, which was made using

`mkdirp('/tmp/uploads', { mode : 0o777 })` ([docs](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp))

had the permissions:

`drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root     4096 Dec 30 01:37 uploads`

Oddly, the user who created the directory (which was the user running the node process) still couldn't access the directory. `chmod 777 /tmp/uploads` fixed the issue.